# check and warp newest files added

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, automation, batch-file

How am I going to automatically check all the files that were added to the directory and then warp it immediately?Because everyday I am downloading hdf files and warping it from time to time is a waste of time. That's why I need it in batch process and automatic.

Thank you in advance!

script:

```
set in_path=path_to_input
set out_path=path_to_output

md %out_path%
cd /d %in_path%

FORFILES /m *A1_AC*.hdf /C "cmd /c gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te 113.205 1.120 157.105 2.005 HDF4_SDS:hdf:@file:01 %out_path%\@fname.tif"*
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort directory content by creation (`/tc`) date (`/-od`) (descending, newest first)

```
dir /o-d /tc
```

then parse the first (**date**) and/or second (**time**) field and compare with the current date (`%date%`) **and** time (`%time%`) with `if` comparison operator:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,5" %a in ('dir /-b /o-d /tc') do @if %a==%date:~4% (if %b==%time:~0,5% (echo %c))
```

selects first (**date**), second (**time**), and fifth (**filename**) fields, if condition is true outputs the last one (`%c`)

---

### notes

- prepending an extra `%` to local `for` variables is required if the code
  is put in a script (`.bat` file)
- time (**short time** on `intl.cpl`) in the machine should be in `H:mm tt` (H=24) format, as `dir`'s output depend on it
- `:~` in `%date%` and `%time%` inside the code is string manipulation (`substring`) operator to make their value comply with the date and time format in `dir`'s output
- scheduled task for checking for events on temporal basis, and running the code/script accordingly can be created with `schtasks` external command (`%windir%\system32\schtasks.exe`)

Comment: How will I create and run the file from the script that you and I have?